# What am i missing when checking to see if a file is a directory or not (in c)?

Tags: c, directory

I feel a bit bad about cluttering up the site with this question, as i've found multiple questions on this topic answered already- but i can't seem to figure out what i'm failing to do, even though i understand the answers i've read.

The goal is to build a file system viewer, but the specifics of that are unnecessary. The part i am struggling with is recursively opening every directory in a directory; i am somehow not checking correctly to see if a file is a directory. A friend is writing a similar program, has the same 'if' statement, and cannot see the difference.

The problem lies somewhere relevant to: if (S_ISDIR(sstat.st_mode)) {

Here is all the code that may be applicable (the program is known to work as desired, apart from its attempts to read a file as a directory when inapplicable). I have a feeling this is a very subtle, stupid mistake.

```
store = gtk_tree_store_new(2, GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF, G_TYPE_STRING);
GtkTreeIter origit[20];
GdkPixbuf* fileicon = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("icon.png", NULL);
build_sys(store, fileicon, getenv("HOME"), origit, 0);

void build_sys (GtkTreeStore* store, GdkPixbuf* fileicon, char* dirname, GtkTreeIter parit[], int depth) {

  GtkTreeIter iter[20];
  struct dirent* sdirent;
  char* dir;
  char* newtail;
  DIR* dirstar;
  struct stat sstat;

  if (depth == 0) {
    gtk_tree_store_append(store, &(iter[0]), NULL);
  } else {
    gtk_tree_store_append(store, &(iter[depth]), &(parit[depth - 1]));
  }
  gtk_tree_store_set (store, &(iter[depth]), 0, fileicon, 1, dirname, -1);
  dirstar = opendir(dirname);
  while ((sdirent = readdir(dirstar)) != NULL) {
    newtail = (*sdirent).d_name;
    if (newtail[0] != '.') {
      dir = dirname;
      strcat(dir, "/");
      strcat(dir, newtail);
      stat(dir, &sstat);
      if (S_ISDIR(sstat.st_mode)) {
        build_sys(store, fileicon, dir, iter, depth + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for your time, let me know if i can improve the post.

Comment: Think about what ends up in the memory pointed to by dirname when more than one file or subdirectory is in the directory being processed. Hint: `dir = dirname;` doesn't make a copy of what is pointed to by `dirname`; it simply becomes another pointer to the same memory. I.e. it copies the pointer, not what it points to.

Comment: Check the results of your `stat()` calls.  And print out names that you're using (passing to `stat()`).  It'll help you debug what's going wrong.

Comment: Yep, exactly as stupid as i expected- thank you @WhozCraig !
Fixed with strcpy().

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty certain at least *one* problem lies here:

```
dir = dirname;
strcat(dir, "/");
```

Since `dirname` is the buffer containing the current directory name, setting `dir` to that will simply give you a pointer to it, then the `strcat` will *modify* the contents of it (not give you a *new* copy as some people seem to think).

That means the next time you use that buffer, it will be the wrong value, something like `/basename/first_file/` rather than `basename/`.

What you probably want to do is build up the test name in a *different* buffer area, something like:

```
strcpy (dir, dirname);
strcat(dir, "/");
strcat(dir, newtail);
```

(ensuring, of course, that `dir` actually points to a buffer big enough to hold the data).

Comment: Yeah... I'm surprised that the OP did not notice the corruption when it ran the code under its debugger :(